# Python ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I append some columns of my data like:

```
        0   0      0       1      0                    
1       0   1      1       0      0     
2       0   0      0       1      0    
3       0   0      0       0      0   
4       0   0      1       0      0
```

And i'd like to make it look like:

```
[0,0,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,1,0]
```

but when I :

```
for i in range(len(re)):
    concat=[]
    for o in range(5):
        concat.append(re.iloc[i,o])
    re.iloc[i,-1]=concat
```

```
    
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 5, in 
    re.iloc[i,-1]=concat

  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 179, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 579, in _setitem_with_indexer
    raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

How can I combine these columns?
I'm a new learner.And my English not very well so that I didn't look through all answers on this kind of case.Thanks.

Comment: what columns are you trying to combine? There are no column headers that I can make out. Is your dataframe called `re`?

Comment: What is that you are trying to do?

Comment: are you looking for tolist()?

Comment: The problem description doesn't make sense. You have not shown how you want the data reshaped. Also, don't call your object re, it is confusing as it is the name of a common python module.